# Is Dantzig-Wolfe decomposition an example of a divide and conquer algorithm?

Tags: linear-programming, algorithms, dantzig-wolfe-decomposition, approximation-algorithms

Typical Divide and Conquer algorithm solves a problem using following three steps:

- Divide: This involves dividing the problem into smaller sub-problems.
- Conquer: Solve sub-problems by calling recursively until solved.
- Combine: Combine the sub-problems to get the final solution of the
  whole

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/divide-and-conquer/

By looking at that general definition, I wonder if it is not, in general, the same process used by Dantzig and Wolfe with their decomposition technique:
Divide: Accomplished by models with a special constraints structure
Conquer: Solve sub-problems
Combine: Combine the sub-problems solutions by convexity constraints.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've never seen D-W referred to as "divide and conquer." While I'm not sure there is a definitive answer one way or the other (meaning I don't know that anyone can say with authority that it is wrong to call it d-and-c), I personally would not consider it a d-and-c approach. My sense is that "divide and conquer" typically refers to a decomposition where each subproblem is solved once. In D-W, both subproblems and the master problem are solved repeatedly.

That said, there is definitely dividing and hopefully conquering when using D-W decomposition.